# Efficient tag combination algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tags, combinations

Let's say I have a store of values:

```
[
   {tags: ["A", "B", "C"]},
   {tags: ["B", "C", "D"]},
   {tags: ["B", "C"]},
   {tags: ["D"]},
   {tags: ["E"]},
   {tags: ["A"]}
]
```

I'd like to be able to take an input of tags, and return the count of the various combinations found within.

For example, let's say I have an input of:

```
["A","B","C"]
```

The various combinations of that input would be:

```
A
AB
ABC
B
BC
C
```

Taking it one by one, I would get the following counts when comparing against the store above:

```
A    => 2
AB   => 1
ABC  => 1
B    => 3
BC   => 2
C    => 3
```

Of course it is obvious that I if I was using SQL I could just do a simple: SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE tag = "A" ...  but that quickly runs out of control for large inputs.

So with all of that as a backdrop, I'd like be able to take an input like above, and return the combination and count like above, but only if it meets the threshold count.  So, something like: SELECT all combinations of [A,B,C] FROM table WHERE said combination has a count greater than 10;

Comment: I don't see a way to do this besides the obvious brute-force method of generating your combinations and checking each store list for them.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll look at more of a data mining approach next.